# Download UX Studio

Tags: e-commerce, commerce-cloud

I am following some commerce cloud tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6d8TJHkfGPw) and trying to download UX studio for eclipse. Unfornately, the link doesnt seem to be working . Does anyone have a link to download  UX studio for commerce cloud?

Comment: have you checked [demandware-ux-studio-installed-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570085/cant-get-demandware-ux-studio-installed-in-eclipse) ?

Comment: Yes the links are not working @glls

Comment: :( sry, wasn't able to get pst the login to validate

Answer (score 2):

The most recent version of the plugin is here: http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.6

Start up Eclipse and use the "Install New Software" link under the Help menu. Paste the URL in the "Work with" entry and give it a name. The rest is dialog based and only requires accepting a license agreement.